# What's an expat XML parser?

Tags: html, web, xml

I found the term here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ

I know what a XML parser is.

I can't understand; what exactly is an **expat** XML parser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) is a specific XML parser. Mozilla's ordinary HTML parser just tries to make the best of what it's given, while a real XML parser is much less lenient, as described on that page.

Comment: Expat (a C library, callable from C++) has a similar approach to SAX, but doesn't follow the SAX conventions. Since SAX was first released for Java, it's conventions have been adapted (with slight modifications) for a range of libraries for other languages, whether Java-related or not - making it a kind of defacto-standard alternative to more heavyweight DOM-based libraries. Expat (IIRC) predated SAX and, although there are SAX-based libraries for C++ (e.g. Xerces-C++), Expat is still going strong. I don't know if there's a SAX variant for C, but it seems implausible without OOP though.

Answer (score 1):

[Expat (XML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expat_%28XML%29) :

> In computing, Expat is a stream-oriented XML 1.0 parser library,
>   written in C. As one of the first available open-source XML parsers,
>   Expat has found a place in many open-source projects. Such projects
>   include the Apache HTTP Server, Mozilla, Perl, Python and PHP. It is
>   also bound in many other languages.